# Doctrine - Returning joined rows as array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Given the following structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdc467/1

I am using Doctrine's query builder and at the minute I can run the query in the fiddle to get the following data:

```
name  | reason       |  SUM(`cost`)
------------------------------------
Tom   | Consulting   |  250
Tom   | Setup        |  50
Tom   | Subscription |  25
Dick  | Setup        |  50
Dick  | Subscription |  25
Harry | Consulting   |  75
Harry | Setup        |  50
```

But I would like to have the data hydrated as follows:

```
array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Tom',
        'charges' => array(
            'Consulting' => 250,
            'Setup' => 250,
            'Subscription' => 250
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Dick',
        'charges' => array(
            'Setup' => 50,
            'Subscription' => 25
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Harry',
        'charges' => array(
            'Consulting' => 75,
            'Setup' => 50
        )
    )
);
```

Is there a way to tell Doctrine to group the `reason => SUM(cost)` values for each user into an array when hydrating?

At the minute I do this by doing several queries and iterating to set up the data as I would like it, but this becomes annoying to maintain as more reasons are added or the structure changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own [Data Hydrator](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html#writing-hydration-method).

That way, you don't have to duplicate the iteration logic, just pass the hydrator to `getResult` and it will manipulate the data for you.

There is a [blog post](https://techpunch.co.uk/development/create-custom-doctrine2-hydrator-symfony2) and you can use Doctrine code base as a source of inspiration: [SimpleObjectHydrator class](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Internal.Hydration.SimpleObjectHydrator.html), [ArrayHydrator class](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Internal.Hydration.ArrayHydrator.html) and [ScalarHydrator class](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Internal.Hydration.ScalarHydrator.html).